# Поиск в БД Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Здравствуйте, дорогие форумчане, мне нужна помощь. В Delphi 7 я произвожу поиск в таблице по коду

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);    
begin
    if not Table1.Locate('Naimenov_ed', Edit1.Text,[loCaseInsensitive, loPartialKey]) then
    showmessage('нету такого') ;
end;
```

Он находит нужную строку, а как убрать лишние строки, чтобы осталась та, которую искал? Или хотя бы изменить цвет у искомой строки. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

См. [поиск и фильтрация данных в Delphi](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/search_and_filter.html).

Раскрашивание грида отдельная задача, ищите примеры про событие TDBGrid.OnDrawDataCell (если другой грид используется надо искать соответствующие обработчики для него), для соответствующих поиску записей менять цвет фона или шрифта... вот, [например](http://pblog.ru/lab/?p=270).

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите насчет фильтраций. Вообще, предлогаю не Table, а Query компонент. Потом средствами SQL это вообще не проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда у тебя вернее сказать задача на фильтрацию, чем на поиск значения. Верно выше говорят, используй Query. Через SQL проще отфильтровать нужные записи.